# What is the best website for runners to record their training?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a site that would allow a runner to very easily:

- blog about each training
- enter number of miles/kilometers run
- have some kind of social media aspect where others can give advice, etc.
- RSS feeds
- number of miles run is totaled
- data dumps from Garmins etc. are possible so all kinds of stats can be recorded

Comment: if you are reading this question you may want to follow/commit area51 site about running > http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6530/running?referrer=wbGGtAbKVUJXXXrT0S5BhA2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [Dailymile](http://www.dailymile.com/) is a social network for runners, triathletes, and cyclists. We make it easy to share your workouts, races, and other cool stuff important to athletes.

Allows you to sync with Nike+ or Garmin devices.

*UPDATE: the Dailymile website closed down in 2019*

Comment: I really like this site for the social aspect. It's great for meeting up with local runners. I've met quite a few over the past year.

Answer (score 7):

[RunKeeper](http://runkeeper.com/) is pretty good and does most of the work for you provided you have a smart phone that you carry while running.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't do everything you want, but I use Adidas miCoach

Which consists of a heart rate monitor, a footpod (for stride length/frequency) and a small datalogger. miCoach let's you pick a training schedule you want to follow and when you start running, it will tell you what you have to do.

Example:

- run in blue zone (heart rate between 130-147) for 5 mins
- run in green zone (heart rate between 147-160) for 30 mins
- run in blue zone for 5 mins

It will tell you to speed up or slow down to follow your training schedule and when you're done, connect it to you computer via USB and it automatically uploads it to micoach.com.

There you can view your heart rate, stride rate, distance and estimate of you burned calories. It keeps track of all your stats over time and will award you achievements for improving your performance and overall stats.  You have easy sharing to Facebook, email or set up a public page. Sadly, no (private) RSS feed or data dump, but the site probably provides all you need.

You can add your running track through Google Maps (and possibly other gps-measurements).

Lastly there's a forum where you can get advice, though the best advice comes from the programs themselves, which are really solid.

Have a look [here for an example](http://www.adidas.com/nl/micoach/WorkoutDetails.aspx?WID=9db9068c-9439-443c-a036-c8ce5f19a41f) from my own 20k in Brussels

Answer (score 0):

I use [mapmyfitness.com](http://www.mapmyfitness.com). Works for any GPS device (iPhone included) or you can log manually. Lots of great features, and even can share routes and workouts with groups. And challenge friends.

Answer (score 0):

[SportsTracker](http://www.sports-tracker.com/) by Nokia is something you should look into.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard some very good things about [Sportypal](http://sportypal.com/). It has a mobile application for almost every platform.

Answer (score 0):

With SportyPal you can easy input your workout into a blog, and share on most of the social networks, as well as upload previously recorded GPX files from other devices

Answer (score 0):

I use [myasics](http://myasics.com) to keep track of my training schedule, progress and records.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through an analysis of sites I could use with my iphone, to combine the GPS qualities of a native phone app with good reports and charting on the web to track my progress. Here's what I looked at:

1. RunKeeper (has free/$10 iphone native app) - runkeeper.com
2. Daily Mile (does not have native app) - dailymile.com
3. NB Fitness / iMapMyRun (both are native iphone apps) - mapmyrun.com
4. Runmeter (only $5 iphone app, no website) - abvio.com/runmeter
5. SportyPal (has iphone native app) - sportypal.com

In the end I chose RunKeeper, and decided to pay $10 for the "pro" version of the app (which has audio feedback). Here's what I thought about the the rest:

Daily Mile is a great site, but needs a GPS app it can sync with for me to get the most out of it. Runmeter is a fantastic app, but you can only export 1 run at a time, and I want automatic uploading of all my runs to a website where I can view charts & reports (still, it worked great last week when RunKeeper couldn't find the GPS!). NB (New Balance) Fitness is a free version of iMapMyRun that I really like, and the mapmyrun.com website is nice, but it iss missing a couple key features for me (like splits and a way to enter my avg HR). Still, I think it's tied with the basic version of RunKeeper for the best FREE app. I wasn't real impressed with SportyPal, compared to the others.

I found the above websites and more in forums (dailymile.com comes to mind) where people have discussed the various trade-offs between these sites/apps at length. If you google a couple different app or website names (e.g. "runkeeper dailymile") you should get even more ideas. Here's a quick brain dump of others:

running ahead
running 2 win
runner+
tracks app / sport tracks
older Garmin-focused list:  http://larrywhocfl.blogspot.com/2008/10/running-sites-that-use-garmin.html

Answer (score 0):

http://www.trainingpeaks.com

Haven't used it much yet, but you can create routes that you walk/run/bike etc